# Storing the variable value across each execution of script - PHP

Tags: php, xml

I have this code:

```
$filename = 'files.xml';
$dom = new DomDocument();

$dom->load($filename);

$oldCount = '';

$newCount = $dom->getElementsByTagName('file')->length;

if($newCount == $oldCount){
echo "There are no new elements in the XML.\n";
}

else {
 echo "New Count is: ".$newCount."\n";
 echo "Old Count is: ".$oldCount."\n";

for ($oldCount =0; $oldCount < $newCount; $oldCount++){
    $file = file_get_contents('files.xml');
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($file); 

    $result = $xml->xpath('file');
    echo "File ".($oldCount+1).": ".$result[$oldCount]."\n\n";
    //echo "Old: ".$oldCount."\n";
    //echo "New: ".$newCount."\n";
   }
   $oldCount = $newCount;
   //echo "Old Count at the end: ".$oldCount."\n";
}
echo "Old Count at the end: ".$oldCount."\n";
```

What I want to do is ensure that the value of `$oldCount` is stored at the end such that, if files.xml has the same number of elements inside the , it would display - "There are no new elements in the XML" when the program is run the second time around.

For test purpose, I have 2 elements in my xml, meaning my xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<files>
  <file>.DS_Store</file>
  <file>ID2PDF_log_2.xml</file>
</files>
```

So, if I run my test.php with only these 2 elements, it should display the info first time. But, the second time I run it, it should display the message. 
It's pretty obvious I am weak at `variable scope` in PHP. 
How can I do this?

Comment: Do you run tour php script in a browser (eg with apache), or as a cli script ?

Comment: You should save previous values at session or db.

Comment: This is not being run on a browser. I'm doing it all on the client and a couple of servers. And I can't really store it in a DB because I do not have that option. Can I still use sessions, if I am not really using a browser, but running the scripts from command line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Command line doesn't support sessions without workarounds, since sessions generally depend on cookies (which don't exist in the command-line) or passing around url query parameters.

Instead, just dump your number out to a file, e.g.

```
file_put_contents('count.txt', $count);
```

then read it in later, e.g.

```
$count = file_get_contents('count.txt');
```

Comment: **DID NOT THINK OF THAT AT ALL.** :( 
Thanks, @Marc . I'll try this. Should work I think. :)

Comment: Small correction!!
It's `file_put_contents('count.txt',$count);` in my case! Works perfectly! Thanks again! :)